# Отчет по зарегистрированным пользователям одним запросом

Tags: база-данных, sql, select, mysql

У меня есть таблица в mysql (InnoDB), в которой указывается, когда пользователь был зарегистрирован.
Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос в базу, который предоставит данные, количество пользователей которые зарегистрировались и были зарегистрированы по месяцам. У меня есть запрос, который выводит количество зарегистрировавшихся юзеров по месяцам:

```
  SELECT 
   COUNT(id) AS count, 
   DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%Y-%m') AS date
  FROM 
   `site_users` 
  WHERE 
   sdate >= $table_date_from
   AND sdate < $table_date_to
  GROUP BY 
   date
  ORDER BY 
   date
  ASC
```

То есть результат получается примерно такой:

- 2014-8 | 1
- 2014-9 | 2
- 2014-10 | 0

Но как сделать так, чтобы тех, кто зарегистрировался раньше, тоже посчитать.

То есть результат должен быть таким (с учетом, что раньше был зарегистрирован один пользователь):

- 2014-8 | 2
- 2014-9 | 4
- 2014-10 | 4

Буду безмерно благодарен, если поможете. Ибо адекватных идей больше нет.

P.S. `$date_from` и `$date_to` -- как не сложно догадаться, переменные, которые указывают, за какой период времени вывести отчет.

Comment: @vtvz, так ты же сам ограничиваешь период двумя датами, а спрашиваешь, как посчитать старых...  
Очень просто, обединяешь два запроса, в одном выбираешь тех, что не входят в твой период, а второй запрос - тот, что ты написал, и объединяешь их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так:

```
SELECT s1.d, COUNT(s2.id) AS count
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%Y-%m') d FROM `site_users`) s1 
   JOIN site_users s2 ON 
     s1.d>= DATE_FORMAT(s2.sdate,'%Y-%m')
WHERE s1.date  < $table_date_to   
GROUP BY s1.d
ORDER BY s1.d
```

Ну или чтоб не строки сравнивать, а числа (побыстрее будет) `DATE_FROMAT(...` заменить на `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM...`